# Why does this code execute?

Tags: java, string

Suppose I have a method called `withoutX` that, when given a string, removes first and last letters of the string if they are x.

My code is:

```
public String withoutX(String str) {
  if(str.length()>0 && str.substring(0,1).equals("x")) {
    str = str.substring(1);
  }
  if(str.length()>0 && str.substring(str.length()-1).equals("x")) {
    str = str.substring(0,str.length()-1);
  }
  return str;
}
```

Why does this return the empty string ("") when str = "x"? Wouldn't the case when str = "x" fail after the first `if` statement because `str = str.substring(1)` references an index that is out of bounds (the max. index of str = "x" is 0)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Wouldn't the case when str = "x" fail after the first if statement because str = str.substring(1) references an index that is out of bounds (the max. index of str = "x" is 0)?

No, because it's not out of bounds: the first (and second) parameters of `substring` can be anything up to the `length()` of the string, not just `length() - 1`. [From the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)):

> [Throws] `IndexOutOfBoundsException` - if beginIndex is negative or **larger than** the length of this String object.

That's larger than, not larger than or equal to.

---

It would be easier (and more efficient) to write this as:

```
int start = str.startsWith("x") ? 1 : 0;
int end = str.length() - (str.endsWith("x") && start < str.length() ? 1 : 0);
return str.substring(start, end);
```

The reason it's easier is that you're simply checking whether the string starts/ends with `x`; `String` provides methods to do that without constructing a substring first.

The reason it's more efficient is that it doesn't create intermediate substrings.

Comment: Also, `? :` has the lowest (except for `=`) precedence, so there is never a need to parenthesize the condition, but often a need to parenthesize the `? :` construct, i.e. you need `str.length() - (str.endsWith("x") ? 1 : 0)`.

Comment: @Andreas typo. Fixed.

Comment: You still didn't fix parenthesis to correct for operator precedence, so that code will not compile. Also, the updated `&& start == 0` means that it'll never remove trailing `x`, if there is *also* a leading `x`. Perhaps you meant this? `(str.endsWith("x") && start < str.length() ? 1 : 0)`

Answer (score 0):

Let's go thorough the code step by step:

```
//str = "x"
if(str.length()>0 && str.substring(0,1).equals("x")) { // both true
     str = str.substring(1);
     //now: str = ""
}
if(str.length()>0 && str.substring(str.length()-1).equals("x")) { // str.length == 0. 
    //Since && does not evaluate the second parameter, everything is fine and if doesn't get called
}
return ""; //as str = ""
```

Comment: OP is asking why `str = str.substring(1)` is not failing. You're not answering the question.